# How to pull a specific row from one spreadsheet to another, update it and then replace it on the original sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have two separate sheets, one with a data list full of unique names, their location and their current status. The second would have an input to type someones name and it would pull up the row that contains their current location/status(first function), from there I could change the status and run the second function that updates the first sheet with the new status. I have been googling all day trying to cobble together something that would work and I think I am almost there on the first function but I am stuck and any help to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Ideally the first function would trigger upon typing the name in and the second would trigger upon changing the status but I can find a manual workaround if need be.

```
    function dataPull() {
     var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Spreadsheet_ID'); //replace with Data spreadsheet ID
     var filteredRows = data.filter(function (data) {
        var employee = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange('b2').getValue();
        if (data[1] === employee) {
        return data
        }
     });
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A2:D').setValue(filter) 
    }
```

Here are some screenshots that will hopefully better explain what I am looking to accomplish.

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASwnU.png)

[Type someones name in Input sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6wyn.png)

[Pull up current status w/ function one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2xzU.png)

[Update Status and run function two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMVTt.png)

[Sample data updates to reflect change in status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PVag.png)

Comment: Why do you not use array formula?

Comment: How do you run dataPull()? Is this function a trigger or just a normal function?

Comment: @user11982798

1st question: 
For pulling the data? My main reasoning would be because I want to be able to overwrite the data and it just seemed cleaner to do it in one fell swoop. 
I guess I don't mind using a separate row if need be


2nd question:
Ideally it would be some kind of 'on cell edit' trigger that activates when a new name is entered but if need be I know (from a different file we use) how to add the function as a menu option

Comment: OK, but you must assign the function as trigger if so

Comment: For your reference, array formula will also over write your cell follow your searcher value, in your sample is B2:B

Comment: @user11982798 Are you talking about using array in the script or as a sheets formula? As a sheets formula it gives me a #ref error if i try to overwrite the line.

If its for the script it's because I don't know how.

Comment: The array formula is not in script but in C2 in your input sheet. If you still want to use script, assign your script as trigger, you must detect wich cell is being active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit Dialog in a Sheet**

There is two sections to this function.  The top section triggers off of edits to the Edit sheet in column 2 and row 2 which is a dropdown that contains all of the name in the Data Sheet. An  edit here cause the top section to run which reads the the data on the Data sheet and file a matching name when it finds it that line is loaded into columns 1 through 4 and row 2 of the Edit sheet.  Then you can edit the status and click the checkbox to save it back to the Data sheet.  The lower portion then runs which reset's the checkbox, clears the Edit range and loads the edits  back into the Data Sheet.

Please take a look at the animation to see the process in action.

Just to let you know upfront, you can run this function from the script editor you must put it into you sheet and name your sheets properly. You must also set up the data validations for the two drop downs.  If you try to run this function from the script editor you will get the **Error: Cannot find method getsheet() of undefined**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('Entry');
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='Edit' & e.range.columnStart==2 && e.range.rowStart==2) {
    e.source.toast('flag1');
    var found=false;
    var dsh=e.source.getSheetByName('Data');
    var vA=dsh.getRange(2,1,dsh.getLastRow()-1,dsh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
      if(vA[i][1]==e.range.getValue()) {
        sh.getRange(2,1,1,4).setValues([vA[i]]);
        found=true;
        e.source.toast('Value Found at i = ' + i + 'value = ' + vA[i][1],'',-1);
        break;
      }
    }
    if(!found) {
      e.source.toast('No Value found = ' + e.value); 
    }
    Logger.log(vA);
  }
  if(sh.getName()=='Edit' & e.range.columnStart==5 && e.range.rowStart==2) {
    e.range.setValue("FALSE");
    dsh=e.source.getSheetByName('Data');
    dsh.getRange(Number(e.range.offset(0,-4).getValue()+1),4).setValue(e.range.offset(0,-1).getValue());
    sh.getRange(2,1,1,4).clearContent();
  }
}
```

Data Sheet:

[image]

Edit Sheet:

[image]

Animation:

[image]

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly! Is this something that would be easy to tweak? Say for example I wanted to be able to add more parameters to the input like maybe date or a couple of others.

Comment: Everything is tweakable.  Easy or hard is relative to what you know.

Comment: So I think I have the majority of it down, the only part I'm not 100% on is: "dsh.getRange(Number(e.range.offset(0,-4).getValue()+1),4).setValue(e.range.offset(0,-1).getValue());"

Comment: That part is what updates Data correct? I thought I could do the third column by switching it to: "dsh.getRange(Number(e.range.offset(0,-3).getValue()+1),3).setValue(e.range.offset(0,-1).getValue());" but that didnt work

Comment: All of those offsets are on the same row so `(Number(e.range.offset(0,-3).getValue()+1)` is the row number.  The column is always 4 and the value to set it to is `e.range.offset(0,-1).getValue()`  This is the kind of thinking that you have to deal with when you're doing all of your calculations in arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the built-in `onEdit(e)` trigger; as it behaves in the same manner as a custom function would eg.(Restricted to the sheet it's bound to).

You can install a trigger in your bound script, and have it execute your un-restricted function.

```js
function importData(e){
  // Get the cell where the user picked its name
  var range = e.range;   
  // The Id of your data source sheet
  var dataSheetId = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX';  
  // Get all values from source sheet as an array  
  var data_values = SpreadsheetApp.openById(dataSheetId).getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  // Return the row with data for matching employee
  var filteredRow = data_values.filter(check)[0];
  // Input location data in input sheet
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(range.getRow(),range.getColumn()+1).setValue(filteredRow[2]);
}

function check(row) {
  // Get the name that the user picked
  var employee_name = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getValue();
  // Check if it matches and return the row
  if (row[1].toLowerCase() === employee_name.toLowerCase()) {
    return row
  }
}
```

You can [install the trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) from within your Apps Script by following ***Edit/Current project's triggers/Add trigger***.

As the *event source* for the trigger select: `"From spreadsheet"`; and for *function to run* select `"importData"` (or the name of your function).